# Java FtpClient Storefile() is Not Working for Big Files

Tags: java, upload, ftp

I am unable to upload more than 3mb files, using Apache FtpClient storeFile() method.., but its working perfectly for small files of size <1mb.

For <1mb storeFile() giving true
But >1mb its giving false..? please help me.

```
client.connect(prop.getProperty("mf.target"));        
client.login(prop.getProperty("mf.userid"),prop.getProperty("mf.password"));    
client.setFileType(Integer.parseInt(prop.getProperty("mf.filetype"))); 
client.setBufferSize(91024000);
//client.setDefaultTimeout(900);
client.setDataTimeout(2900);


boolean flag = client.storeFile(prop.getProperty("mf.dataset.src"), in);
```

Do we need to add any thing more, please advice.

Comment: timeout problem? why do comment setting timeout value out? try to increase it

Comment: am not seeing any difference with that defaultTiimeout, thats why i gave comment. by the way, its not working even i increased the timings ?  if i upload 3mb file its uploading some 1200kb around, and storeFile() method returning false.

Comment: can you upload using some other FTP client succcessfully?

Comment: I am running by application by making it jar, and through putty.

Answer (score -2):

first question: is there any upload limit policy on your ftp **server**, preventing uploading files larger than 3Mb?

Comment: you better put question in comment to the original post

Comment: No Olivier, we can upload any size file.